# Unable to locate package tsodbc

Tags: ubuntu, freetds, tdsodbc

I'm trying to install FreeTDS as explained in the [django-pyodbc wiki](https://code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/wiki/FreeTDS). But the last package fails to install:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install tsodbc
 ...
 E: Unable to locate package tsodbc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct package is [tdsodbc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/tdsodbc) not `tsodbc`. You can install it by typing `sudo apt-get install tdsodbc` in the terminal.